# Sync delta of two databases

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, mariasql

I am currently choosing a database structure that I would like to work as follow:

-One local database, will have new inputs each second (key - timestamp).

-One cloud database.

-One script that takes the delta between the local and the cloud DB, and update the cloud DB. The connection on the local server can go up and down, so the script will not be able to execute each time. Therefore I want the delta to be synced!

I have looked into using MySQL and MariaDB, but havent seen a way where I can easy sync a delta and not the whole DB. Is there an efficient way to perform this?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for [replication](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/setting-up-replication/). No need to "roll your own".

Answer (score 0):

Cron job that copies everything after the cloud's timestamp from the local db.  Or, simply a continually-running job that does that with a "sleep 1" in the loop.